# Hashing Json result to detect changes

Tags: c#, .net, json, hash

I get **JSON** results and parse them to models and store them in database. I need to check if the result is *new to insert*, or if it *has changed to update* existing data. Consider that I am getting JSON results according to *list of URLs*. As there can be a lots of URLs I do not want to check all data against database. Instead I want to *hash results* according to URLs and store these hashed values for given URLs in *database*. Next time when I get JSON result according to that URL I want to hash it again, *check if this value is different from last hashed value*, if it is different then parse and compare whole model against database, if nothing is different then skip. **Is this correct approach? Are there any better options?**

If it is OK to implement such algorithm, **what hash function should I use** considering that JSON results are not very large. I know that *according to MSDN* **GetHashCode** is not consistent for strings in C#, as far as I know they even *use BuildNumber in Debug mode* to make developers avoid persisting results from GetHashCode method. I planned to use MurMur but read that MurMur is good for large sets of data and not ideal for hundreds bytes of information.

Comment: Why not use something like SHA-256? Strong cryptographic hashes are designed to make it bolt-of-lightning unlikely that you'll end up with hash collisions for genuinely different inputs, and they're widely implemented in many different languages/platforms.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for reply. I will check out SHA-256. I haven't worked with any of hash functions so I can tell that I do not know anything about them. I read a lot of warnings about not persisting hash values and  I know that there can be rare collisions for different inputs. But, as I *do not use it for uniqueness*, instead I just detect changes for same input, my main question is "is it OK to use and persist hashes for this purpose?"

Comment: Are those urls arbitrary or selected ones? I am asking it because if properly implemented those endpoints might use the [`Last-Modified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) or [`ETag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Etag) response headers which are designed exactly for this kind of purpose and you won't need to be doing the heavy lifting on the client. It's already there, built straight into the HTTP protocol.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, It is not that random, but arbitrary is much closer. In the future there can also be HTML results, so I want to detect it myself, instead of relying on provider.

Comment: The aforementioned response headers are not constrained to JSON only, they apply to HTML as well, as long as the remote resource uses them. But if you cannot rely on those headers, then your approach with calculating the hash and storing it in the database is valid. You are fine even with MD5 for this kind of purpose. For example Amazon use it for calculating the `ETag` header (:-D) of their S3 resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already a mechanism built straight into the HTTP protocol that is designed exactly for this purpose: the [`ETag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Etag) and the [`Last-Modified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) response headers. This would work if you have control over the endpoints that you are consuming and that they are following best practices and using those headers.

If this is not the case, then you might need to be doing the calculation on the client side, as you already hinted, by calculating a checksum of the contents and then comparing against a previous checksum. [`MD5`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is a pretty fast algorithm and commonly used for this purpose. For example Amazon use it for calculating the `ETag` header of S3 resources.

Comment: Thanks for answer. If I got it right, *calculating checksum* means *calculating hash*, am I right?

Comment: Yes, exactly - checksum and hash is the same thing.